# How to validate textbox array elements created through loop using VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have created 288 textboxes through array and loop in VB.net. Is there any possible way on validating each textbox on KeyPress event to determine if the input is an integer? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: try my solution, if it helps accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding event handler in the array function.

```
Dim txt As TextBox
AddHandler txt.KeyPress, AddressOf KeyPressToCheckInput
```

then write the KeyPress Function

```
Sub KeyPressToCheckInput(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
  If e.KeyChar <> ChrW(Keys.Back) Then 'checks for backspace
    If Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) Then
     'anything you want to do about it'
    Else
     e.Handled = True 'ignores if the character is not a number
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```